# Raise a click event automatically on the newly created elements by the javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, I am creating some new tr nodes in a table using the insertAfter,

```
        let row = $('#'+Reports.proID);
        let info;
        let expOp;
        let html = '';
        Reports.getOrdersBySo()
            .then(function (data) {
                info = JSON.parse(data);
            })
            .then(function(){
               let html = updateMainTableBySo(info['data']);
               $(html).insertAfter($('.sort-table tr:eq('+row.index()+')')); // updating the table, function create tr by class order-by-so
               $("tr.order-by-so").each(function() {
                    let currRow = $(this);
                    let expOp = currRow.find('td:eq(1)').click();
                  });
                let cl = document.getElementsByClassName('orderByOp');
                console.log(cl.length);
            })
```

When "Order by so" class is created as you can see, I am iterating over this class and raising the click event on the second td element of the tr, This also create some tr elements by class name orderByOp, Now I am unable to iterate over all the tr elements of orderByOp class to raise click event on them.
This is worthy to note that, I think dom is unaware of these new classes when I iterate over these, but I get

```
   let cl = document.getElementsByClassName('orderByOp');
```

this show two elements in dome with the classname, but the length of cl is 0. How to achieve the required result please help.

Comment: document.body.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
  if( event.srcElement.id == 'btnSubmit' ) {
    someFunc();
  };
} );

Comment: Can you show us the markup?

Comment: By "Raise a click event" do you mean to trigger it, or to handle the event when it triggers or to add an event handler to the new rows in the table that it appears you are appending? `.find('td:eq(1)').click();` appears as if you wish to trigger it but it can likely be done easier than we you are attempting there.  By showing the HTML it would help us a great deal in helping you

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that demonstrates issue. Your click approach looks ugly but a very short `setTimeout()` might change results. We can't see what the click event handler does though

Comment: it might be as simple as  $("tr.order-by-so").find(('td:eq(1)').trigger('c lick') but `orderByOp` is NOT the same as `order-by-so`

Comment: Yes I want to raise it automatically, in the same way as I raised for order-by-so @MarkSchultheiss

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly messy but I think something like this is what you describe

```js
var mysecond = function(me) {
  console.log("triggered me",$(me).text());

  $('.orderByOp').trigger('click');
};
$('#mytable')
  .on("click", "tr.order-by-so >td:eq(1)", function(event, callback) {
    let row = $(this).closest('tr');
    console.log("td:", $(this).text());
    row.append('<td><button class="orderByOp">Order BY Op</button></td>');
   if(callback){ callback(this);}
  })   
  .on("click", '.orderByOp', function(event) {
    console.log("td:", $(this).text());
  })
.find("tr.order-by-so >td:eq(1)").trigger('click', [mysecond]);
```

```css
td {
  border: solid green 1px;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="order-by-so">
      <td>first</td>
      <td>second</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```